# Is there a way to remove input elements if the value is null?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a problem with my input element, it has a null value. Can I remove the input element instead? and is there any way of it? thank you. Here is a picture of the problem

[image]

> Can I remove that input text with null values instead?

I am using js and ajax to call those values in my database. Here is my script file

```
showAllQuestions();

//function to get data
function showAllQuestions(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>teachers/showQuestions',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            var html = '';
            var i;
        for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            html +='<div class="card">'+
                        '<div class="card-header">'+
                            '<h4>Multiple Choice</h4>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="card-body">'+
                                '<form>'+
                                    '<div class="input-group">'+
                                    '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
                                            '<span class="input-group-text">Question</span>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<input type="text" name="question" value="'+data[i].question+'" class="form-control" required>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<hr>'+
                                    '<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">'+
                                        '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
                                            '<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Choice 1</span>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+data[i].choice1+'" name="choice1" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">'+
                                        '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
                                            '<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Choice 2</span>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="choice2" value="'+data[i].choice2+'" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">'+
                                        '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
                                            '<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Choice 3</span>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="choice3" value="'+data[i].choice3+'" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">'+
                                        '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
                                            '<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Answer Choice</span>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="answer" value="'+data[i].answer+'" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</form>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
                }

                $('#showdata').html(html);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not get Data from Database');
            }
        });
}
```

And to show, I enclosed it on a div tag

```
<div id="showdata"></div>
```

Comment: see template literals, and then put a condition for the input string elements

Comment: @EugenSunic - kindly help me with the logic of the code please, is there any functions ill create or do? still understanding the parts of it.

Comment: `<input>` elements can't have a `null` value. The value is always a string.

Comment: You will have to TEST each of the choises to make sure you only put out what you want to put out

Comment: It's simple. Just check `if(!data[i].choice1)` then only appened the Choice 1 `input-group input-group-sm mb-3` parent div and do the same for `choice2` & `choice3` also.

Comment: @palaѕн - hello sir, can you please give me an actual example please. thank you. where should i put the logic? outside the script?

Comment: Inside the for loop only where you are appending to the html variable.

Comment: @palaѕн - hello sir, I tried doing it before but then the choices have disappeared.

Comment: @palaѕн - hello here is how i changed it. please see, sir. `if(!data[i].choice1){
          '<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">'+
           '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
            '<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Choice 1</span>'+
           '</div>'+
           '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+data[i].choice1+'" name="choice1" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>'+
          '</div>';
          }`

Comment: yes, you are there. Just need to add `html +='.....'` all the code inside if statement. Since right now it is appeneded to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `null` check where you add the variables to your string. `null` being a `falsy` value, you will have an empty value if the variable is `null`:

```
'<input type="text" class="form-control" value="'+(data[i].choice1 ? data[i].choice1 : "")+'" name="choice1" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" required>'
```

Comment: Just beware that this will also remove the number value `0`. If that is a valid value, you should probably only replace `null` and `undefined`. E.g. `(data[i].choice1 == null ? data[i].choice1 : "")`

Comment: @Anurag Srivastava - hello, the null has been removed, but the `input element` was still there. it hasn't been removed. I am expecting that `question text input and answer text input` will only shown.

Comment: Though it will not make any sense to have a question with no choice at all.

Comment: @palaѕн - hi, the answer is the `answer input element or choice 4` i am making the backend process where teachers can create questions.

Comment: Checkout @palaѕн's comment on your question. Typically you will need to breakdown the buildup of your html into parts, and add html conditionally.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava - should i do it outside the script?